# Look for file ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I am trying to learn unix. I wanted to set up a sort of file watcher that looks for files and returns the file names so i can move them from source to processing folder to process. It echos File Found I just cannot figure out how to capture the file name.

```
#determines if file exists
if  [ -f  * ]; then 
    echo "File found"
else 
    echo "File not Found"
fi  

# returns file to array
#Needs name still
NewFiles[0] = 

#output what what found in 0 index
echo "Found File"
echo NewFiles[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files have no fancy names (embedded spaces or similar), you might use that approach:

```
set -- *
[ $# -gt 0 ] && {
    echo Found file
    echo $1
}
```

Comment: This is safe for files with "odd" names (other than not quoting `"$1"` when passed to echo).