# Get Filename from Directory KSH Unix

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Ok I asked a question about a week ago and got a response that works but does not solve my problem. I am new to KSH. Also a good explanation would be helpful I would rather have a starting point or somewhere to start reading rather than already wrote code. :) I want the finish product to look like this:

```
iter = 1
do
   while fileExistsInDir==true
   $arr[$iter] = filename
    iter++
    done

 #do something with the array
```

In my previous question I was told to do this

```
set --*
[#$var -gt 0]&&{
 echo $1 
}
```

this worked but the $1 i had to keep increment i.e. $2, $3, $4 and so on. I want that to stay static and change the value for each file. Is there a easier way to do this. everything i have seen on stack so far has either needed dependencies  or does not seem to work.

Comment: So you just want a numerically-indexed array holding the filenames in the current directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36754231/3220113 used spaces, remember they often are significant.

Answer (score 4):

To get all the files in the current directory into an array is very easy:

```
$ arr=(*)
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
```

The `*` is called a *glob construct*, but most people call it a wildcard.  It means "filenames in the current directory of zero or more characters"  (i.e. all of them).  I am assuming a relatively recent version of ksh.  Array handling in Korn shell has changed over the years.

Comment: Is this better than what i am doing now using the set?

Comment: It's simpler, and simple is good.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle Some people have issues with using `set` - I don't.  There are a few obscure issues with `set`, but there isn't much to choose between the methods.

Comment: When you are using a shell without arrays then using `set` is necessary. The problems with using `set` are that it blows away any positional parameters your script/function have received so if you still need those that's a problem. If you have arrays then using `set` is an option but using an array works just as well (and you have more of them to play with).

Comment: Good practice assigns positional parameters to named parameters (variables) near the start of the script, so using `set` to overwrite them should not be an issue.  This is specifically Korn shell, but a different syntax is required for ksh88.

Comment: Thank you for the information it helps me understand this much better

Answer (score 2):

The line `set -- *` globs all the files in the current directory into the positional parameters.

You can loop over all the positional parameters with

```
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: The `in "$@"` part is optional, and the default.

Comment: @cdarke Agreed. And normally I'd have left it off but in this case I thought the added specificity was useful given the specific setting of positional parameters by way of `set --`. (Though it would have been more useful if I'd called out that `$@` is the array of positional parameters.)

Comment: Thank you this explains it better. Is this the best way to do this process?